# Magento checkout not working after upgrading to 1.9.3.1

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, upgrade

Just had magento upgraded from **1.9.2** to **1.9.3.1** and checkout has stopped working. When they get to `Checkout > Checkout Method` they con't checkout as a Guest or Register as a new user.

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely `due to your present theme's checkout review step incompatibility with the latest version 1.9.3.1.`

To fix this you can follow these steps below. This will work in most of the cases.

1. **Comment out** or **remove** the **review** folder in the template path *`/magentoroot/app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/checkout/onepage`* This will fallback to the default base theme and make the final step works. This will fix this issue in most of the cases.
2. Use **Firebug console / Google developer console - Network tab** `to identify the issue in the AJAX Post action after the place order button has been clicked` and apply the appropriate code to fix the issue.